# Cypress fixtures structure json and type

Tags: json, cypress, fixtures

i have one form with two inputs

```
context('Include contains from json file', function () {

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.server()
        cy.fixture("example.json")
            .as('data')
            .then((data) => {
                cy.route('GET', 'example.json', data)
            })
    })

    it('Výběr klienta', function () {

        cy.visit('/info')
        cy.get('[data-cy=username]').type(JSON.stringify(this.data)
        cy.get('[data-cy=surname]').type(JSON.stringify(this.data)
    })
})
```

How to type contains for two or more inputs from external file .json

My .json file

```
{
  "name": "Jane"
  "surname": "Doe"


}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `this.data.name` and not `JSON.stringify(this.data)`

Answer (score 0):

1. The `.json` file should be in the **fixtures** folder as cypress will automatically search for test data inside this folder by default until and unless the path is specified otherwise.
2. You have to load the fixtures file in your tests in beforeEach() `cy.fixture('example.json').as('data')`
3. Then your code would be:

   ```
   cy.get('[data-cy=username]').type(data.name)
   cy.get('[data-cy=surname]').type(data.surname)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me perfectly in single fixture JSON with multiple data and not stub API

before describe('Test Single Input Field Form', function() declare :

`const testData = require("../../fixtures/multipleInputFields.json")`

and then

```
`testData.forEach((data) => {  
const message = data.message 
it('Test Case', function(){      
cy.log("data is:" + data) 
cy.get('#user-message').type(message).should('have.value', message) 
cy.get('#get-input > button').click()  
cy.wait(200) 
cy.get('span#display').should('have.text', message)      
}) 
});`
```